# Dropdown Menu Bootstrap bug quando clicado

Tags: html, css, menu

Eu implementei um menu dropdown (bootstrap) básico no meu site. Ele funciona normalmente quando clicado no início da página, porém, se eu rolo um pouco pra baixo e volto pro topo da página, e clico novamente nele, ele, por algum motivo que não faço a menor ideia do porque, aumenta a largura do site inteiro, e o menu é jogado para o canto direito.. Segue print para facilitar o entendimento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta print é o menu quando clicado sem rolar nenhuma vez pela página.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta print é o menu clicado logo após dar uma leve rolada pra baixo no site.
Se alguem puder dar uma  ajuda, agradeceria demais!!

o codigo do menu é este:

```
    <div class="dropdown" style="padding-top: 2%; width:100%; min-width:250px; padding-right:7%; ">
    
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="border:none; background-color: transparent;">



        <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style=" margin-right: 0%; border:solid; color:#C4C4C4;  border-radius:50%;">
        
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nav" aria-hidden="true"></span</button>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="width:100%; margin-right:10%; ">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ 'novo'|page }}" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFFFF, #EDEDED);"><h2>Home</h2></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ 'ofertasnovo'|page }}" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFFFF, #EDEDED);"><h2>Ofertas</h2></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ 'credenciadasnovo'|page }}" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFFFF, #EDEDED);"><h2>Credenciadas</h2></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

edit: Não entendi o motivo de derem dado 3 downvotes na pergunta, se me dissessem o porque eu arrumaria..

Comment: Pode nos dizer qual é a versão do bootstrap? Pelas classes eu suponho que é a 3.x, pode confirmar? Existe algum lugar que você possa subir seu site para que possamos vê-lo?

Comment: é a versão 4.0.0, o site ta upado aqui: http://fasttire.com.br/novo

Comment: Confira os estilos do dropdown. Ao que me pareceu, algum dos estilos definidos inline parece estar afetando o dropdown, possivelmente o botão que mostra o dropdown seja o culpado, pois quando eu troquei a sua marcação pela padrão da documentação do bootstrap não ocorreu novamente o problema.

Comment: hmmm entendi, vou dar uma mexida no botão!!! MUITO obrigado pela resposta!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

O Bootstrap leva em prioridade o seu estilo padrão. Esse erro pode estar acontecido devido a alguma alteração de estilo que você fez em seu CSS, ou entrando em conflito com algum outro framework que você está usando (se caso estiver).